# Question about preposition of 'in'

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions

I'll show you two sentences concerning the preposition of 'in'.

> 1) I'm interested in traveling.

In this sentence, there seems to be two possible definitioins to me.
First, taking part in something. Second, concerning something.

> 2)She kicked him in the stomach.

Also, I think that there are two possible definitions to me.
First, concerning something. Second, at the point within an area or a space.

Source : https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in

I'm not a native speaker as you know. There are many confusing definition in preposition to me. It seems to be mother-tongue problem. It is hard to get clear meaning of words and sentence concerning translation. Sometimes, some seems to be similar. I think that a little difference is very important. Is there anyone who let me know correct answer above sentences?

Answer (score 1):

The word *in* is used in so many ways that the Oxford Learners' Dictionary can't cover all of them.

*Interested in* is a standard phrase for someone who is keen to take part in an activity or to learn about it.

*In* is often used with a part of the body when an action is applied to it, for example 'look him in the eyes,' 'poke him in the ribs' etc. Sometimes it's *on* - 'pat him on the back'. You just have to learn which preposition is used where.